# Bulgarian contest problem about finding integral solutions to a diophantine equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math

ADAPTED FROM A BULGARIAN MATH OLYMPIAD PROBLEM:

Find all pairs $(x,y)$ satisfying $x^3$ = $y^3$ + $2$$y^2$ + $1$

MY ATTEMPT: I first tried taking the cubes to one side, and rewriting th given eq as:

$(x - y)$$($$x^2$ + $xy$ + $y^2$) $=$ $2y^2$ + $1$

I don't know where to take this, since $2y^2$ + $1$ isn't given to be prime or anything like that. I also noticed, however, that $2y^2$ + $1$ seems to return a prime whenever we input an odd value of y, but I don't know how to prove this, or that it's even true.

Hints would be appreciated, thanks!

Comment: You will probably notice that $y^3<y^3+2y^2+1<(y+1)^3$ for almost all of the $y$'s. Thus, $y^3+2y^2+1$ can't be a cube power most of the time. You have a few cases to analyse though.

Answer (score 0):

Size matters.  $x$ is bigger than $y$ and so $x^3$ is at least as big as $(y+1)^3,$  So you have

$$x^3 = y^3+2y^2+1 \geq (y+1)^3 = y^3+3y^2+y+1.$$

So that

$$0\geq y^2+3y.$$

The only integer solutions of this inequality are $y= -3, -2, -1,$ and $0$.  Each of which give a solution.

Comment: Note that $y=-1$ is actually not a solution; R.H.S. $=(-1)^3+2(-1)^2+1=-1+2+1=2$. But there clearly does not exist a integer $x$ s.t. $x^3=2$.